# how to write a mysql view which uses a column name from data in a table

Tags: mysql

I have a "parameters" table containing in its data a column name ("col1"), which is one of the columns in my "mydata" table.

```
parameters
==========
which_column    
-----------
"col1"


mydata
======
col1    col2    col3
--------------------
6       7       42
1       2       3
5       9       11
```

I need the write a mysql view which selects from "mydata" depending on the column specified in mydata

### edit:

i want to do something like:

```
create view myview as
    select mydata.(select which_column from parameters) from mydata
```

i have 24 different column names so i do not want to manually test for each case.

Comment: You can probably do with dynamic sql... however, will this data be changing?  What / how many values will you be dealing with.. equality, ranges, etc...  Will there be multiple rows with different columns you are querying for?

Answer (score 1):

In case table parameters contains only one row with column name this should work:

```
SELECT which_column FROM parameters INTO @param;
SET @qry = CONCAT('SELECT ', @param, ' FROM mydata');
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @qry;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

Comment: how does this go inside a view?

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked a view requirement, can you use stored function instead of view?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  IF(@parameter='col1',col1,IF(@parameter='col2',col2,IF(@parameter='col3',col3,null))) AS mycol
FROM
  tablename;
```

This is q&d, but it works.